# Integração com API de Pagamento Juno

Tags: php, integração, pagamento-online

Estou com dificuldade ao finalizar a autenticação com a api 2.0 da Juno.
Ela está pedindo o grant_type=client_credentials, porém já tentei quase tudo mas tudo que consegui foi um erro 400.

Link Doc
https://dev.juno.com.br/api/v2#operation/getAccessToken

```
$data = $info;
    $base64 = base64_encode("$clientID:$clientSecret");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.juno.com.br/authorization-server/oauth/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;',
        'Authorization: Basic '.$base64.'',
        'Host: api.fullprog.dev',
        'grant_type=client_credentials&clientId='.$clientID.'&clientSecret='.$clientSecret.''
    ];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $json = json_decode($server_output);
    $status = $json->status;
    if ($status == '401') {
        $errorMessage = $json->error;
        $ErroMensagem = $json->message;
        $time = date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime($json->timestamp));
        echo 'Em '.$time.' ocorreu um erro. <br>Detalhes: '.$errorMessage.' Complemento: '.$ErroMensagem;
    }else{
        if (isset($json->error)) {
            echo $json->error.' informa: '.$json->error_description;
        }else{
            print  $server_output ;
        }
        
    }
```

Ele me retorna:
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Ou

invalid_request informa: Missing grant type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve fazer assim:

```
<?php

$clientId = "ggdsgsdgd";
$clientSecret = "fsdhshtegeTl#50dS5o4e<;wzzD";

$base64 = base64_encode("{$clientId}:{$clientSecret}");

$ch = curl_init("https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/authorization-server/oauth/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization: Basic {$base64}"
]);
$resultado = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));


var_dump($resultado);
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pela resposta, eu já estava me perdendo aqui pra aprender. Muito obrigado